# Pulling images from Delve in an SPFx web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have created a web part which will find the members of an Azure AD group.
I am hoping to display each members profile picture.
I do this by using this address for each member

https://sfeur.delve.office.com/mt/v3/people/profileimage?userId=joe.bloggs%40mytenant.com&size=L

This will work but ONLY if I open a browser to Delve before I run the code.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0):

The issue is authentication - if You don't visit Devle before there are no auth cookies available hence nothing will be displayed.

I recommend using Graph API to get user photo, You can find a tutorial here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

You can also use a npm package to help You with it:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mgwdev-m365-helpers

Hope this helps